# Eigen: std::set with VectorXd

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to use `std::set` together with `VectorXd` from the Eigen library:

```
typedef VectorXd Vec;

bool(*fn_pt)(Vec,Vec) = vecCompare;
set<Vec,bool(*)(Vec,Vec)> yx (fn_pt);
```

The function vecCompare ist defined as follows:

```
bool vecCompare (Vec v, Vec w) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numCrit; ++i) {
    if (v(i) < w(i)) return true;
  } 

  return false;
 }
```

Unfortunality, yx.find(x) does not work correctly, i.e., it returns an empty iterator even if x is already in yx.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Is `numCrit == v.rows()` (and `== w.rows()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vecCompare` is not a total ordering. It returns `true` if any coordinate in the left operand is lesser than the corresponding coordinate in the right operand. For the vectors a = (1, 2), b = (2, 1), for example, both `vecCompare(a, b)` and `vecCompare(b, a)` are true.

If you meant a lexicographical ordering, this should work:

```
bool vecCompare (Vec v, Vec w) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numCrit; ++i) {
    if (v(i) < w(i)) return true;
    if (v(i) > w(i)) return false;
  }

  return false;
}
```